Great Expectations status markers in data-docs are not visible
What could be the reason that I could not see "red" or "green" status  success/fail markers in data-docs in Great Expectations? Even old ones, which previously were visible, now are not visible:

I have tried different browsers and different GE versions, still the same situation, just suddenly they became not visible.

GX made a fix, so updating to 0.18.22 version will resolve this issue.

from IPython.display import display, HTML
validation_results = validation_definition.run(batch_parameters=batch_parameters, run_id=RunIdentifier('testing_ge'))
validation_results.meta["expectation_suite_name"] = suite_name
document_model = ValidationResultsPageRenderer().render(validation_results) display(HTML(DefaultJinjaPageView().render(document_model)))
enter image description here
enter image description here
This was the closer I got the status icon to work but it is broken still and did not function directly with context.build_data_docs(site_names=site_name)
Edit: I'm using GX integrated with kedro and when i run the validations on kedro data, all status markers work. Without it still doesn't work.

I discovered this same issue on the same day. I traced it to a Font Awesome toolkit.  is forbidden. Seems someone at GX made some configuration change and broke this. I posted a message on their support Slack channel: https://greatexpectationstalk.slack.com/archives/CUTCNHN82/p1727894175388099 But no reply

I also opened an issue on their channel: https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/10475
